# Spring Webflow , Primefaces with Comet (Atmosphere)

Tags: comet, primefaces, spring-webflow, atmosphere

Thinking to start a project using Spring Web Flow with Primefaces.  I need to use comet so i figured Primefaces uses Atmosphere. I'm not really experienced with the Atmosphere  / Comet business so any pointers about where to start is welcomed.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a very basic example can be found in the primefaces showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.xhtml
This is the old example for the ajax push component and is NOT officially included in the show case right now because it will be redone in primefaces 3 if I know right. In addition to that you have to configure the comet servlet within your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Comet Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.comet.PrimeFacesCometServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>org.atmosphere.useBlocking</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Comet Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primefaces_comet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you use primefaces 2.2 you cannot use the newest version of atmosphere/comet I think. I got it running with the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-compat-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

The last step is to add a file named "atmosphere.xml" within your META-INF directory with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<atmosphere-handlers>
  <atmosphere-handler context-root="/primefaces_comet/*" class-   name="org.primefaces.comet.PrimeFacesCometHandler" />
</atmosphere-handlers>
```

Jens